# How to load video from web url in android

Tags: android

I am loading browser url from using  webservice in video view it take  time  to load can anybody tell  how to show progress bar upto video view is loaded in android?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lot of tutorials for this kind of stuff out there.   Here's one for using an AsyncTask with a progress bar widget within the current activity:  http://www.codingforandroid.com/2011/06/basic-asynctask-with-progress-bar.html

Also, in the official android docs, there's an example of showing a progress dialog with a 2nd thread:  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

To check the videos progress and dismiss the dialog, you'll need something like this:

```
mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer arg0) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        mVideoView.start();
    }
});
```